# Using Tkinter set() attribute with grid layout in python

Tags: python, layout, grid, tkinter, set

I've tried a number of different ways to use the Slider `set()` in tkinter with the grid layout and I cannot get it to recognize the attribute.

Here's a functional version not using set():

```
master = Tk()
master.title("This is a title")

Scale(master, from_=0, to=100, label='Brightness').grid(row=0, sticky=W)

master.mainloop()
```

This works as would be expected.  But if I change to:

```
Scale(master, from_=0, to=100, label='Brightness').set(50).grid(row=0, sticky=W)
```

I receive:  `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'grid'`

If I try to assign the scale to a variable with `set()` and then use that variable with `.grid(row=0, sticky=W)` I receive the same thing.

What is it that I am missing here?  I looked through the docs, but it seems there's little on `grid()` as compared to `pack()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
scl = Scale(master, from_=0, to=100, label='Brightness')
scl.set(50)
scl.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
```

[set](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scale.htm#Tkinter.Scale.set-method) method returns None. You are getting None type error because of that. As you can see from above code, you should first assign to a variable then use methods on that variable.

Comment: Thanks Lafexlos!

I tried that with:
#bright=Scale(master, from_=0, to=100, tickinterval=10, label='Brightness')
#x=bright.set(50)
#x.grid(row=0, sticky=W)

Uncommented of course and it wasn't working.  But I restarted the kernel with your code and it did it.  Much appreciated.

Sorry for the code being jumbled.  My newlines are being removed for some reason.

Comment: If you look my code, I use methods(set and grid) on variable without assigning them to anything else because those methods are widgets' methods. If you assign to `x` after `set`, that `x` will be `None`. So your code in comment would be, `bright.set(...)` and `bright.grid(...)`